# How to get an array from another class

Tags: java

I can't seem to find an answer for this, I have a lot of different arrays, and I want to stuff all of them into one class, to make my main one neater.

```
Testy obj = new Testy();
```

But i have no clue on how to get an array from here. Sorry if this is a bad question, this is my first time posting on the site. I'm just trying to get an array called testArray from the class called Testy.

Code inside Testy:

```
public class Testy {
public static void ArrayTesting(){
    int testArray[]={56,1,4,175};
}}
```

Comment: You need to show us where the arrays you want are now, and where you want them to be.

Comment: Yes it's a bad question because you're not telling any of the necessary details. Please ask it with en eye towards our situation: folks who have no idea of what your code looks like or what you've tried and how it's not working.

Comment: Don't only describe your code, post it. To do so use [edit] option.

Comment: post the codes in your Testy() class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to get any variables from another class is to create a getter for that particular variable. After that, you can call the getter in order to get the value of whatever variable you want.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    //Variable I want to return
    private int[] numArray = {1, 2, 3};

    public int[] getNumArray() {
        return numArray.clone();
    }
 }
```

and you can call it by saying

```
MyClass newClassObj = new MyClass();
int[] secondArray = newClassObj.getNumArray();
```

Comment: Arrays are mutable. It's better to clone it before return to the caller